# Approximating real valued complex function with real part of complex valued polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f:\{ z\in\mathbb C: \|z\| = 1\}\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $p(z)$ is an analytic polynomial with a complex coefficient. For all $\epsilon>0$, does there exist $p(z)$ such that
$$
|f(z) - \Re (p(z))| < \epsilon
$$
I think this is related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640174/hahn-banach-theorem-in-boundary-set-of-complex-disc).

Comment: I think you meant `for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist $p(z)$ such that'. Otherwise it is not approximation, but rather $f(z) = \Re(p(z))$.

Comment: @Riemann yeap, i'll fix it

Comment: If I understand correctly this, for each $\epsilon >0$ you want a $p_{\epsilon}$ with the required property; since the real part of such is just a real harmonic polynomial (and conversely any such gives an analytic polynomial by taking it's harmonic conjugate which is also harmonic real polynomial), and on the unit circle this is just a real trigonometric polynomial, the result comes down to Weierstrass approximation theorem which is well known and follows for example using Feijer theorem on the uniform convergence of the means of the Fourier partial sums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to asking for the $L^\infty$ convergence of Fourier series of a continuous periodic function. To see this, note that the function $t\mapsto f(e^{it})$ is a periodic, continuous real valued function, and if $p(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ is a polynomial, then $$\Re (p(e^{it}))=\sum \Re(a_ne^{int})=\sum b_n\cos(nt)+\sum -c_n\sin(nt)$$ where $a_n=b_n+ic_n$ is the decomposition into real and imaginary parts. To answer that question, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60427/convergence-of-fourier-series-in-l-infty-norm), for instance.

Comment: I disagree a bit with the statement about equivalence to convergence of the partial sums of the Fourier series, since you can take their means and still get the real part of a polynomial and those converge uniformly by Feijer's theorem